# mysqli prepared statement not doing anything

Tags: php, mysqli

The prepared statements are giving me problems.  I can read data from the database, but unable to write.  Here is the prepared statement that I am having trouble with.  No errors, but nothing happens when the code executes.  Thanks.

```
 /*Prepared statement option 1*/

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT USERS (userEmail, userPassword, userFname, userLname) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

/*prepared statement option 2*/

    $query = "INSERT INTO users (userEmail, userPassword, userFname, userLname) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $query);
```

/*Bind statement*/

```
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssss', $userEmail, $userPassword1, $euserFname, $userLname); 

/* execute prepared statement */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); 

/* close statement and connection */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Comment: you are typed one additional `s` here `'sssss'`

Comment: `No errors` - *really*? Or did you just not [inspect](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) [them](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php)?

Comment: I'm sure you already checked the return value of `mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)`...

Comment: corrected. I had a lot of entries, but cut it down to 4 to present to stackoverflow, left an extra s.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Always** have this line right before connecting to mysqli:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Comment: Thanks!!!  Now I am getting an error.  I should be able to figure it out now.  Must be something to do with the userID.                    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'Column 'userFname' cannot be null